# Can I stop parsing all other code the instant a script is executed to redirect a user to another page?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to stop the parsing of all other scripts. A condition which redirects a user gets recognized onload. I'm still seeing a lot of stylesheets and js being parsed though. Is there any way to kill all other parsing and continue with redirect?

```
<script data-cfasync="false">
function MyFunc(){
    var x = -1; //For example
    if (x===-1){
        document.location = "myurl.tld";
        //I want to kill all other parsing or loading here and proceed with redirect
    }
}

window.onload = MyFunc();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [`window.stop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/stop):

> The window.stop() stops further resource loading in the current browsing context, equivalent to the stop button in the browser.

Note that attaching a function to the `load` event will run only *after* the window has been fully loaded. If you want to try to redirect immediately (so that `window.stop` actually stops further processing ASAP), call `MyFunc` immediately.

```
function MyFunc(){
  var x = -1; //For example
  if (x===-1){
    window.stop();
    document.location = "myurl.tld";
  }
}
MyFunc();
```

Or, if you have to, wait for `DOMContentLoaded`, which will have loaded the DOM, but may not have loaded all scripts, images, and other resources (which the `load` event waits for):

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', MyFunc);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate this solution & the clarity around on-load!

Comment: Hey thanks again, I was wondering if there was anyway to maintain onclick function scripts after window.stop()?

Comment: The only thing to do is delay when you call `window.stop`. If the script that attaches the listener runs after you call `window.stop`, it won't run at all. I suppose you could monkeypatch `addEventListener` or `onclick` so that they run your script when called, ensuring that only the minimal required amount of page code is parsed, but that's a *really* odd thing to try to do.

Comment: Hey thanks again for your help, the addEventListener worked perfectly. I don't think I monkey patched it (not sure what monkeypatching is) but the functions in the event listener worked after window.stop. Really appreciate the suggestion!

It's probably very unconventional, but did wonders for my page speed. I'm unfamiliar with Ajax, server-side stuff, and programming in general, so I couldn't figure out how to use load a section on condition and stop everything else. You were a life-saver!